# Sudoers CLI options

Tags: bash, sudo

I'm working on a sudoers file. What is the correct way to state the following?

Zero or more command line options, each starting with a single or double dash, followed by one or more characters. I want to effectively allow both long and short command line options, zero or more total, e.g. -v --variable -vb, etc.

I believe that the following would be the appropriate perl regex.

```
... <binary> (?:-{1,2}\w+)* <file>
```

I'm not sure exactly how to translate that into something bash /sudoers compatible.

Comment: Am I interpreting you correctly, if you say that you want to be able to run the binary with any number of arguments - regardless of what they are? Or do you actually want to do some filtering here?

Comment: Any number of arguments, but they need to be in the syntax of actual arguments --value, -v, not potentially a second file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sudoers` file allows shell-style wildcards, but it does not support regular expressions. For the specifics of what you *can* do natively, see the "Wildcards" section of the [Sudoers manual](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html).

The best thing to do in this situation is simply write a script that validates input using your regex, then either terminates with an error (if invalid) or passes the input on to the specified binary (if valid). You could write such a script easily using perl, Ruby, Python, or whatever pleases you most. Give your sudoers access to the script instead of the binary.